# Error When Trying to Create a MUnit Test: Could Not Create a New Suite File for Your MUnit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to create a MUnit Suite from a test as is done in the following video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzcNAmWPw9MvWUhoLXZweUtWZ3c/edit?usp=sharing

When I right-click the flow and choose "MUnit->Create new $FlowName Suite", I see a pop-up that says "Could Not Create a New Suite File for Your MUnit Tests". There is no traceback or any other error information to infer what went wrong.

When I try to create an Munit test using the wizard, I get the error "Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)". Again, there is no traceback or any other error information.

The above happens when I do this with any Mule Flow.

The following is the software that I have installed:

- Anypoint Studio: Build ID 201410161901
- Operating System: CentOS 6.3
- Munit: 3.5-M2
- JDK: 8.0.25

What could the real problem be?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC nor Mule or MUnit in 3.5-M* did support Java8 neither for run or build.